# Adobe AIR 3.3 Update Framework

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I am building an application in AIR (v3.3) using Flash (NOT Flex), and I am having trouble with the update framework. All the resources I have found are for older versions of AIR and / or refer to a Flex build.
It's the first time I have done this, and would really appreciate some guidance...

I have a simple test app - an image (which changes v1 to v2) and a text field.
This is what I have tried (following http://goo.gl/uvycg):

```
...
var appUpdater:ApplicationUpdaterUI = new ApplicationUpdaterUI();
...
public function checkForUpdate():void
    {
        ...
        appUpdater.updateURL = "http://mysite.com/updates/update-descriptor.xml";
        appUpdater.isCheckForUpdateVisible = false;
        appUpdater.addEventListener(UpdateEvent.INITIALIZED, onUpdate);
        appUpdater.addEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR, onError);
        appUpdater.initialize();
    }
private function onUpdate(event:UpdateEvent):void
    {
        txt.text = 'onUpdate()';
        appUpdater.checkNow();
    }
private function onError(event:ErrorEvent):void {
        txt.text = 'onError() ' + event.toString();
    }
```

This is my updateDescriptor.2.5.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<update xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/framework/update/description/2.5">
<versionNumber>2.0</versionNumber>
<versionLabel>Beta 2</versionLabel>
<url>http://mysite.com/updates/UpdateTest.air</url>
<description>               
    <![CDATA[ update of bees. geometric growth. ]]>
</description>
```

So, the update descriptor with v2 of the app is on the server, I install and run v1 of the app, and all that happens is I see the onUpdate() message in my text field, and no update happens.
Where am I going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: are you in debug mode or you are testing with exported app ?

Comment: I am testing with an exported app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/air/update/ApplicationUpdaterUI.html#checkNow%28%29), it would appear that you need to make sure the current state of the ApplicationUpdaterUI is "ready," otherwise "checkNow()" will do nothing.

The most recent information on Adobe AIR updating can be found [HERE](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7ff2.html). It applies across the board.